# How to extract the values inside the keys of a list of dictionaries into a dataframe using the indices inside the keys as headings?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am following this tutorial: https://www.datacareer.co.uk/blog/openfigi-permid-api-accessing-financial-market-instruments-unique-identifiers-in-python/

It maps some data into a list of dictionaries, the object is called 'job results', it states that for every ticker inside 'job results', the 'key' is called "data". Inside the keys 'data', are a list of values, which we are trying to extract into a dataframe using the indices as the headings.

`python`

```
just_dictionaries = [d['data'][0] for d in job_results]

df_figi = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(just_dictionaries)
df_figi
```

That is the code I tried. However, when running it, Python get an error message as such:

```
KeyError: 'data'
```

I then tried my own code:

`python`

```
for i in job results:
  for valueSet in object['data']:
     print(valueSet)
```

Thanks in advance! my code seems to have been a step in the right direction. However, I am not sure how to get it into a dataframe. So to summarise, my question is: why is the author's code not working and what must I change to get it to work?

EDIT: snippet of the data in 'job_results' has been attached as requested in the comments section.

```
[{'data': [{'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'US',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UA',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB08W9',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UC',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB09P5',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UN',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0BD3',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UP',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0BS7',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UB',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0D03',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UT',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0DK1',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UM',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0DY6',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UX',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0FH0',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UD',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0J82',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'UF',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0M21',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'VY',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0N65',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'VJ',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0NV7',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'VK',
            'figi': 'BBG000BB0P60',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000BB07P9',
            'exchCode': 'VF',
            'figi': 'BBG00DJCT5K9',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BARRICK GOLD CORP',
            'securityDescription': 'GOLD',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001S5N9P3',
            'ticker': 'GOLD',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0010005500001001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None}]},
 {'data': [{'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000C9KL89',
            'exchCode': 'US',
            'figi': 'BBG000C9KL89',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BROOKFIELD ASSET MANAGE-CL A',
            'securityDescription': 'BAM',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001SF86D7',
            'ticker': 'BAM',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0023964300002001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000C9KL89',
            'exchCode': 'UA',
            'figi': 'BBG000C9KLS7',
            'marketSector': 'Equity',
            'name': 'BROOKFIELD ASSET MANAGE-CL A',
            'securityDescription': 'BAM',
            'securityType': 'Common Stock',
            'securityType2': 'Common Stock',
            'shareClassFIGI': 'BBG001SF86D7',
            'ticker': 'BAM',
            'uniqueID': 'EQ0023964300002001',
            'uniqueIDFutOpt': None},
           {'compositeFIGI': 'BBG000C9KL89',
```

Comment: Post the data in job_results

Comment: If your data is exactly same as you have attached, then the script is working fine

Comment: @bigbounty Thats very strange, because I copied everything straight from my code, and on my side I still get the same error. Thanks for assisting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dataframe is capable of reading results straight from JSON, no need to convert into a dict.

You can initalise it by using `json_normalize` by using the following:

`df = pd.json_normalize(job_results, 'data')`

where `data` is your record path.

[You can read the docs on json_normalize here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)